# uitextfield not updating after switching view controllers

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a uitextlabel that is updated using an nstimer.

When I switch to another view controller (storyboard segue) and back again the text label is no longer updated (returns to default text), even though the timer continues to run.

The timer is writing a value to the uitextlabel which stops working after switching.

NOTE: the `updateTimerLabel` method continues to output the correct info but the label is not updated.

```
headerfile
NSString *timerTicksForCounter;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self updateTimerLabel];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self updateTimerLabel];
}

- (void) startLastConUpdater
{
    lastCTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
}

-(void) updateTimerLabel
{
    NSLog(@"timer: %@", timerTicksForCounter);
    if (timerTicksForCounter) {
        NSLog(@"timer not null");
        mainTimerLabel.text = timerTicksForCounter;
    }

}

- (void)updateTimer
{

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:stopDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];

    timerTicksForCounter = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    [self updateTimerLabel];
}
```

Comment: Can you show some codes?

Comment: check my comment - not sure how to get the NSTimer to continue updating the text field using your suggestion below. rgds

Comment: check the answer now, If it is useful please accept it. it will help for others.

Comment: updated with your code but still having same problem. I've updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your textField text in

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self updateLabel];

}
```

First Declare

```
NSTimer * countdownTimer;
NSUInteger remainingTicks;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    remainingTicks = 60;
    [self updateLabel];

    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target: self selector: @selector(handleTimerTick) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void)handleTimerTick
{
    remainingTicks--;
    [self updateLabel];

    if (remainingTicks <= 0) {
        [countdownTimer invalidate];
        countdownTimer = nil;
    }
}

-(void)updateLabel
{
    timeLabel.text = [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt: remainingTicks] stringValue];
}
```

Comment: how do I do that? The text field is updated every second (is a timer) using an NSTimer.

Comment: @user1542125: user label to display timer is enough. not need to use textField

Comment: I have implemented your solution as above..but it still does not update the label. Also, I have a label not a text field..typo.

Comment: did you call ' [self updateLabel]; ' in viewWillAppear method?

Comment: yes - I have updated my post with my code. Have I done anything wrong??

Answer (score 0):

```
    //sent notification


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];


    **//Get (Retrive) Notification**


         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) 
                name:@"TestNotification"
                object:nil];

   //Get notification method. 

        - (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
        {
            // [notification name] should always be @"TestNotification"
            // unless you use this method for observation of other notifications
            // as well.

            if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
                NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");

        **//Here write your code for update textfield**

        }
```